# How to power Rpi 3, Arduino Uno and IC´s with 5V 2A

Tags: arduino, power, integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi

I want to power a Rpi, Arduino Uno and some Ic´s and sensors parallel.
My problem is how do I split the Amps over all the components that they are not damaged.
Because the IC´s e.g. only can handle 50mA and the Pi a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about 'splitting amps between components'.  Each component will only pull the amount of amps that it requires to operate.  What you do need to worry about is ensuring that each component can operate at the voltage you are applying to the system.

Comment: Exactly. The voltage matters, not the amps. You could theoretically power your Pi on 5V 60A if you want to and it would not smoke. If all your components are operating at 5V, you can safely attach everything onto 5V 2A (or more amps).

Answer (score 0):

When stuff is connected in parallel Amps get split properly automatically. You only really need to make sure that the voltage is correct and there is enough filtering to absorb any voltage spikes.

The spec sheet of each component will contain a suggested capacitor to put between ground and VCC.